# Color changing background animation

Tags: html, css, animation, background

I am currently working on a website and I want to have an animation where the background changes color at certain points.

```
@keyframes background_color {
    0% {
        background: #dfdfdf;
    }

    15% {
        background: radial-gradient(rgb(143, 50, 224, 0.6), #dfdfdf );
    }

    35% {
        background: radial-gradient(rgb(143, 50, 224, 0.6), #dfdfdf );
    }

    50% {
        background: #dfdfdf;
    }

    100% {
        background: #dfdfdf;
    }
}
```

The percents seem kind of weird, but they match with the movement of another animation. Basically, I want the color to change 9 times where it goes from default background to color change back to the default background and then repeat 9 times with different colors.

I tried java and other things like that, but I don't know what to really do.

Comment: I doubt the statement that you tried Java as a replacement for a CSS animation. You probably mean JavaScript. CSS-anmiation will run through all declerations and changes the value between them automatically to have a fluent switch. The animation will not shoe a certain color at one point and then swap it back to default. You explicitly have to declare the swap

Comment: What do you want it to look like? You seem to be trying to animate between a color and a gradient which I can’t quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function secondFrame() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("ok");
        document.getElementById("back").classList.remove("one");
        document.getElementById("back").classList.add("two");
    }, 16000);
}
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

@keyframes background_color1 {
    0% {
        background: #dfdfdf;
    }
    15% {
        background: red;
    }
    35% {
        background: blue;
    }
    50% {
        background: green;
    }
    100% {
        background: #dfdfdf;
    }
}

@keyframes background_color2 {
    0% {
        background: #141414;
    }
    15% {
        background: red;
    }
    35% {
        background: blue;
    }
    50% {
        background: green;
    }
    100% {
        background: #141414;
    }
}

.one {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: 5s ease-in-out 1s 3 both background_color1;
}

.two {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: 5s ease-in-out 1s 3 both background_color2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body onload="secondFrame()">
        <div class="one" id="back"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In CSS, you can change ***3*** to ***9***.
And In javascript, you can change ***16000*** to ***5 * 9 * 1000 + 1*** - It's waiting second.

Hope your success!!!

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with css yes, and I can see that you forgot to add in "animation-duration".

try this:

```
/* The animation code */
@keyframes example {
    0% {background: #dfdfdf;}
    15% {background: radial-gradient(rgb(143, 50, 224, 0.6), #dfdfdf);}
    35% {background: radial-gradient(rgb(143, 50, 224, 0.6), #dfdfdf);}
    50% {background: #dfdfdf;}
    100% {background: #dfdfdf;}
} 
/* The element to apply the animation to */
body {
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

you can read more here on how this work:  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: he did not forget to add `animation-duration`, he didn't share the part that triggers the animation. However, the issue is within the animation itself which you completely ignored.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).